# How to make puppeteer work with Firebase Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I create the endpoint "/getpdf", and deploy the function to firebase. The result should be a pdf download in the browser. But when I request it I get an 404 Error. When I test the same app without firebase  (with express app.listen) it works fine and the pdf gets downloaded. When I not use puppeteer, and try for example a simple request.send("Hello World") firebase functions works.

All firebase settings are on default.

Would be great If somebody can help me and show me a way to download a pdf file created by puppeteer through firebase functions.

thanks in advance

```
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const app = express();
app.use(function cors(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8');
    res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=some_file.pdf');
    next();
});

app.get('/getpdf', async function getpdfHandler(req, res) {


    var browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });

    try {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setContent("<html><head></head><body><h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1></body></html>")


        const buffer = await page.pdf({
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,
            margin: {
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px',
                right: '0px',
                bottom: '0px'
            }
        })

        res.type('application/pdf').send(buffer);
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e.toString());
    }

    await browser.close();

});

exports.getpdf = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with puppeteer.  You're just accessing the wrong URL to invoke the function.  It's not going to work exactly like it does if you run a local express server.  Please edit the question to be specific about what you're doing to invoke the function.

Answer (score 2):

I made a mistake in the combination of express and firebase. If I do it without express, then it works. This completes my question:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

exports.getpdf = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {


    var browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });

    try {

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setContent("<html><head></head><body><h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1></body></html>")


        const buffer = await page.pdf({
            format: 'A4',
            printBackground: true,
            margin: {
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px',
                right: '0px',
                bottom: '0px'
            }
        })


        res.header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8');
        res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=some_file.pdf');
        res.type('application/pdf').send(buffer);




    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).send(e.toString());
    }

       await browser.close();

});
```

Comment: I'm thinking of moving from Amplify to Firebase due to the restrictions on Lambda file size, and Puppeteer being about 250mb.  Does this function just deploy without any issues??